# Cant find database table with node stickiness

Tags: entities, database

I watched into Drupal 7 database, but i cannot find a table where nodes have stored their "sticky" value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find field in node table as mention @clive

[image]

Comment: Yeah.. i see.. i oversaw an pagination. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look harder!

The `node` table has a `sticky` column, the data is stored there.

Comment: You were right! i forgot that database has a pagination.. my bad.. Thanks for your effort anyway!